# cbind and combine in R

Tags: r

I am little confused here: 
I have this variable `gene <-c("IDH3G", "SSR4" )`. when I do
`c(gene,gene)`, I get: 
`"IDH3G" "SSR4"  "IDH3G" "SSR4"`, but when I do `cbind (gene, gene)`, I get :

```
  gene    gene   
[1,] "IDH3G" "IDH3G"
[2,] "SSR4"  "SSR4"
```

Shouldn't this be same as what we get from `c(gene,gene)`?  Can someone please clarify?

Comment: were you expecting `cbind(matrix(gene, nrow=1), matrix(gene, nrow=1))`?

Comment: @baptiste Yes that is what I was expecting, like if `gene` had multiple rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `c` function combine the vectors and generate a vector character.

```
class(c(gene,gene)) 
[1] "character"
```

but `cbind (gene, gene)` consider the `gene` as a vertical vector and combine them to  make a matrix:

```
 class(cbind (gene, gene))
[1] "matrix"
```

From R help `?cbind`:

> Combine R Objects by Rows or Columns
>
> Description:
>
> ```
>  Take a sequence of vector, matrix or data-frame arguments and
>  combine by _c_olumns or _r_ows, respectively.  These are generic
>  functions with methods for other R classes.
> ```

Comment: Thanks, got it! `cbind` always arranges vector element in serpentine order across the matrix.